# Unable to get column name and column lable in sql server result set meta data

Tags: java, sql-server

Can anybody help me to get actual column name and its alias using ResultSetMetaData by connecting to sqlserver database.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

class MysqlCon {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=alcoa", "sa", "test");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT std_code as \"Student code\" from Student ";

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            ResultSetMetaData rsm =rs.getMetaData();
            for (int i = 1; i <= rsm.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println(rsm.getColumnLabel(i) + "--" + rsm.getColumnName(i));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
Student code--Student code
```

Above code works as expected in other database like mysql and oracle.

I checked code for [SQLServerResultSetMetaData](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerResultSetMetaData.java#L101). Both methods [getColumnLabel](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerResultSetMetaData.java#L101) and [getColumnName](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerResultSetMetaData.java#L106) are identical.

[abzycdxw65](https://github.com/abzycdxw65), has raised same issue on their [github account](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/975). it is closed.

Is there any way to get following output:

```
Student code--std_code
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question you can try the followings to retrieve column names

```
select name from sys.columns
```